# eclipse -vm %JAVA_HOME% in eclipse.ini fails

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded eclipse adt and there is no jre in eclipse folder.

So I created on Windows 8 a JAVA_HOM environement variable pointing to my JDK path and added this line to eclipse.ini

-vm %JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw.exe

but eclipse still looks for jre in its sub directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use environment variables in the eclipse.ini (Eclipse bug [102239](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show%5fbug.cgi?id=102239)), you must specify the actual full path.

You must also put `-vm` and the path on separate lines.

If there is a `-vmargs` entry in the eclipse.ini the `-vm` must come before that.

Comment: "You must also put -vm and the path on separate lines." oh my that's why I did put in same line.